# mtbserver requires keychain access after deleting Xamarin

Tags: macos, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I had Xamarin studio installed on my macbook pro, and then deleted it a while ago. However, every time I startup my mac, I still get a keychain access request from mtbserver. I have found many posts explaining how to delete all xamarin related files, but still this keychain request persists. Anyone had this issue and managed to solve it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I finally found that xamarin installs in this directory "/Library/LaunchAgents"  this file "com.xamarin.mtvs.buildserver.plist". You got to remove this file from "/Library/LaunchAgents" this prevents launching "mtbserver".

Comment: Fwiw, this file is installed by Xamarain.iOS and not Xamarin Studio.